# How can I use Cloudflare Image Resizing for React Native App

Tags: react-native, mobile, cloudflare

I am storing images for a React Native App on Cloudflare Images. Unfortunately Cloudflare Images does not support density, thus I would need Cloudflare Image Resizing - which I unfortunately can not activate as I do not have a domain connected.

Is there any way to use Cloudflare Image Resizing, especially the responsive image service, for a React Native app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-native-compressor` to resize images and then, to show responsive images, you can use `react-native-responsive-image-view`.

Comment: I would like to supply only the necessary image instead of resizing it on the device. My aim is to use this functionality: https://developers.cloudflare.com/images/image-resizing/responsive-images/#srcset-for-high-dpi-displays

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can You please provide your implementation ?